# Sticky header of table with sticky table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to create a html table (or something similar looking) with a fixed header and a fixed first two column.The table should be below div not on the top of page . I tried many solution , In all solution having fixed position , due to this table display on top line of page .

As in jsfiddle link.

[http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_programmer/z3bzv9j8/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_programmer/z3bzv9j8/1/)

Header of table displaying on top . I want Table with header should be display below div with background color yellow. Content in div will be dynamically . It can we increase.

My css :-

```
.tblTitle{
   position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    background:lightblue;
}
td, th{
    padding:5px;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    font-size:14px;
}

#vertical_scrolling_div{
    display:inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display:inline;
    padding-top:40px;
    height:300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#freeze_container{
    display:inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}
#horizontal_scrolling_div{
    display:inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display:inline;
    width:200px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.freeze_table{   
    background-color: #0099dd;
    z-index:2;
}

#left_table{
    width:100px;
}

#inner_table{
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Javascript :-

```
$(function(){  
    function getRows(rows, cols){
        var rowString="";
        for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
            rowString+="<tr>"; 
            for(var j=0;j<rows;j++){
                rowString+="<td>"+j+","+i+"</td>";
            }
            rowString+="</tr>"; 
        }
        return rowString;
    }

    $("#left_table").append(getRows(2,10));
    $("#inner_table").append(getRows(8,10));
});
```

And html code :-

```
<div style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">Test-1</div>

<div id="vertical_scrolling_div">
    <div id="freeze_container">
        <table id="left_table" class="freeze_table">
            <tr class='tblTitle'>
                <th>Title 1</th>
                <th>Title 2</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="horizontal_scrolling_div">
        <table id="inner_table">
            <tr class='tblTitle'>
                <th>Title 3</th>
                <th>Title 4</th>
                <th>Title 5</th>
                <th>Title 6</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want the header of the table and first two columns fixed (position: fixed)?? or some other kind of fixing??

Comment: Yes i want table and first two columns fixed , but below div not on top of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I updated your code to fit your needs, the table header remains on top of the div (fixed).

```
.tblTitle{
    position:absolute;
    background:lightblue;
    top: 0;
}
.vertical_scrolling_div {
    position: relative; /* rest other code stays as they are */
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#vertical_scrolling_div').scroll(function() {
    $('.tblTitle').css('top', this.scrollTop+"px");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z3bzv9j8/9/

Comment: It's not working , Table header still showing top of page , I want it below div.

Comment: table header is top of `vertical_scrolling_div` and not on the top of the page. have you seen my fiddle?

Comment: @praveen_programmer I missed to tell one line - `position: relative` on `.vertical_scrolling_div`

Answer (score 0):

Your headings are not aligned well, because you've set the `position` to `absolute` on your header tags, try replacing it with `position:relative` on your  `.tblTitle` tag, and you will see them located below the **Yellow** div, from this point, apply the proper styling, and make it look however you like to to be.

Comment: I tried this but issue is this , I want header should be fix on scroll, But it's not happening .

Comment: well, change it to position:fix, remove your top:0, and add margin-top:-50px; --> https://jsfiddle.net/Escape_Character/z3bzv9j8/5/

Comment: But issue is this when I increase content in div dynamically . Table header overlap on div.

Comment: how does it overlap ?

Comment: Like my updated code in js fiddle . div height will be auto .Here we can load data dynamically.